# New packages installed through Node.JS not working: 'You may need appropriate loader to handle this file type' & others'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install

First of all everything seemed to be working fine until today when I needed something to parse my HTML to a React component.

Here is the full error log:

```
2016-10-26 20:59:58,453 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack: ERROR in ./~/entities/maps/decode.json
2016-10-26 20:59:58,454 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack: Module parse failed: /opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/entities/maps/decode.json Unexpected token (1:4)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,454 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
2016-10-26 20:59:58,454 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:4)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,454 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp$4.raise (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,454 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp.unexpected (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,454 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp.semicolon (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,455 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,455 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,455 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,455 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,455 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,457 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.parse (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,457 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Object.parse (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,457 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Parser.parse (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,457 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,457 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,457 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at nextLoader (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,458 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at /opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
2016-10-26 20:59:58,458 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at Storage.finished (/opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,458 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at /opt/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vma/ui_cache/node/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
2016-10-26 20:59:58,458 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
2016-10-26 20:59:58,458 [INFO] vm-agent.webpack:  @ ./~/entities/lib/decode_codepoint.js 1:16-46
2016-10-26 20:59:58,481 [INFO] ws4py: Using epoll
```

If necessary, here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './react',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
    }
};
```

I have already looked through a few threads with the same problem, unfortunately none of their solutions have worked for me.

Comment: `{ test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }`   https://github.com/webpack/json-loader